# How to setup header and footer when using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, footer

How to set header and footer on an html page when using angularjs? Is their a way so that angular knows that these are header and footer and positions them at top and bottom of page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either define your header and footer html in your main layout (index.html) or include it using ng-include:

```
<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
<div ng-view></div>
<div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
```

Positioning is determined by CSS.